# Experiment changing strongly held attitudes or beliefs

Tags: experimental-psychology, belief, persuasion

Has there been an experiment replicating the **change of a strongly held belief or attitude** in the psychology literature? I understand that this is an extremely difficult phenomenon to replicate, and one that would likely take months. However, given the need that politicians and influencers have to gain public support, I find it difficult to believe that such an experiment has not been attempted. Examples of strongly held beliefs or attitudes include political party affiliation, religious affiliation, or attitudes to race or polarizing politicians.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  Since you are asking about a replication, can you please provide a reference to the original experiment that you are asking about?  The *attitude change* field is quite large and involves many experiments of changing people's minds, so it would help to narrow down what you are looking for.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Sorry, by replication I meant replication of the phenomenon, not any particular experiment. Yes, there have been many experiments on __attitude change__ but none that I have found focused on the change of a strongly held one and that is what I am looking for.